# Decide if the next infinite series are convergent or divergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need help with this problem:

Decide if the next infinite series are convergent or divergent. The tools that you need to use are the Leibniz Theorem, the Comparison Test, Quotient Test and the Integral Test.

> 1. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {{\sin\ (n\theta)}\over{n^2}}$
> 2. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n {{\log\ n}\over{n}}$

I don't know how to start. Can you please help me and explain me how to decide when to use one of the tests? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$. Note that, Every absolutely convergent series is convergent.

Now, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^2}|\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. So, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin (n\theta)}{n}$ is absolutely convergent and hence convergent.

$2$.For the second one we use alternating series test. Set $a_n=(-1)^n\frac{\log n}{n}$ then, $|a_n|=\frac{\log n}{n}$ decreases monotonically as $n>\log n$ for all $n>1$ with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. Hence the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\log n}{n}$ converges.

**EDIT:** [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), [Absolute convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence), [value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function)

Comment: How did you found that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^2}|\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$? Why did you choose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$? Sorry I find this topic pretty difficult.

Comment: Oh, I see. Recall that $|\sin x|\le 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ so each term of the $n$-th partial sum of the above series i.e. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N |\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^2}|$ is less than $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $N=1,2,...$

Comment: Or, simply $|\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^2}|\le\frac{1}{n^2}$ and take finite sum both sides then take the sum to infinite sum.

Comment: So $|sin(n\theta)|$ is always $\leq 1$?  And then the inequality will remain when we divide by $n^2$, right?

Comment: absolutely correct. and it is true for all n and for all theta.

Comment: Okay, I see it know. For the second one, why is $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$? I understand that $|a_n|=\frac{\log n}{n}$ and taking the limit tends to 0, since as you said $n>\log n$ for all n.

Comment: We know that $x\le |x|$ for all real $x$. Now $a_n \le |a_n|\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n \le \lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|=0$ so the limit on the R.H.S is zero.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just one more question, how can I see which test method should I use?

Comment: I had asked this question to my teacher long ago he told me to spend more time with series, and it works! I don't have any prominent answer to this question. If you find my answer suitable kindly upvote the answer and accept it.

Comment: Sure. One question, does the second one change if instead of $\log n$ it is $\ln n$?

Comment: In general in calculus: $\log x = \log _{10} x$ and $\ln x = \log_e x$

Comment: Yes, I know, but I wrote it as $\log x$ because my teacher uses $\log x$ as $\ln x$, not as $\log_{10} x$, does it change the way the problem is solved?

Comment: No. It doesn't change the procedure. If someone does not specify the base of the log and he writes $\log$ in calculus we, in general, mean $\ln$. If you still want to proceed, the substitution may help you $\log_{10} x = \frac{\ln x }{\ln 10}$